# Target Packages Configured Twice....Lies

Tags: package-management

**ERROR:**

```
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list:1
```

**I used a script I found on here to clear duplicates, and it works, and I have gotten back "no duplicates".**

Detects and interactively deactivates duplicate Apt source entries.

Usage:

```
sudo python3 apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries.py
```

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import aptsources.sourceslist

EMPTY_COMPONENT_LIST = (None,)

def get_duplicates(sourceslist):
    """
    Detects and returns duplicate Apt source entries.
    """

    sentry_map = dict()
    duplicates = list()
    for se in sourceslist.list:
        if not se.invalid and not se.disabled:
            for c in (se.comps or EMPTY_COMPONENT_LIST):
                key = (se.type, se.uri, se.dist, c)
                previous_se = sentry_map.setdefault(key, se)
                if previous_se is not se:
                    duplicates.append((se, previous_se))
                    break

    return duplicates


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        input = raw_input
    except NameError:
        pass

    sourceslist = aptsources.sourceslist.SourcesList(False)
    duplicates = get_duplicates(sourceslist)

    if duplicates:
        for dupe, orig in duplicates:
            print(
                'Overlapping source entries:\n'
                '  1. {0}: {1}\n'
                '  2. {2}: {3}\n'
                'I disabled the latter entry.'.format(
                    orig.file, orig, dupe.file, dupe),
                end='\n\n')
            dupe.disabled = True

        print('\n{0} source entries were disabled:'.format(len(duplicates)),
            *[dupe for dupe, orig in duplicates], sep='\n  ', end='\n\n')
        if input('Do you want to save these changes? (y/N) ').upper() == 'Y':
            sourceslist.save()

    else:
        print('No duplicated entries were found.')
```

**Checked my sources list, and there are no duplicates**: 
http://4.1m.yt/ZpBycBf.png and http://2.1m.yt/Wh3BMA.png

**Sources list 2:**    2.1m.yt/BJ84IEB.png (sorry only allowed 2 links >.>)

```
kali@ADELL:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls 
canonical_partner.list
canonical_partner.list.save
mefrio-g-ubuntu-plymouthmanager-xenial.list
mefrio-g-ubuntu-plymouthmanager-xenial.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list
noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-themes-xenial.list
noobslab-ubuntu-themes-xenial.list.save
rodsmith-ubuntu-refind-xenial.list
rodsmith-ubuntu-refind-xenial.list.save
```

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/779962/edit) your question and show us the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list` and your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Yep, sorry. There you go.

Comment: @Kali, Could include copy paste contents as text of both files mentioned by Videonauth. The picture attached shows only 35 lines where the error message was clearly indicated line 40?

Comment: Computers don't lie. To them, this is truth because it was *told* this.

Comment: @Sneetsher i just looked it up line 40 is the canonical partner line in the vanilla sources.list. See my answer below.

Comment: @Videonauth, nice shot :), I just didn't want to delete canonical_partner.list blindly without checking its contents.

Comment: The funny thing is, the above script never would detect this duplicate. I'm still not sure from which dinosaur Ubuntu version or where that canonical partners.list came from, for sure not from a newer installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.k. quick fix for you:

```
sudo su
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list.save
```

The next block you can copy and paste completely to the terminal and hit enter once:

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
EOF
exit
```

After that simply do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And I'm pretty sure your double entries messages are gone.